# How to find an element by jquery when ID is same for many field

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am stuck with a problem the scenario is we have a web application where in users click on some link and opens a page as TAB user can click create as many tab as he wants of same page but at server we must identify request came from which tab so that we can retrieve data correctly.

To identify the tab in our layout we have kept a hidden field and assigning a GUID for the first Ajax call . Then we have a written a Ajax interceptor which is intercepting any ajax call finding the hiddenfield byid and then attaching it to the header of the request.

But the problem is

```
  angular.element( '#angularAppId' ).val();
```

this is retrieving the value of first tab not the one where user has done the activity we need to get hiddenvalue from the active tab how can I do that

In ajaxinterceptor how do we get to know from which document the ajaxcall was made

Comment: ***when ID is same for many field*** `ID should always be unique`

Comment: multiple fields having the same ID is never recommended. It should be always unique.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID :) As said before, ID must always be *unique*

Comment: We have the hiddenfield in layout page.. So ID is same .. we want to access the document from where ajax call was made in the Ajax interceptor how can we do that

Comment: as many others said - ID must be unique. Use selection by css class instead

Comment: in that case css calss name would be same how to know if it has retrieved the value from current tab

Answer (score 0):

Comments stated that id SHOULD alaways be unique.

However they are very wrong.

It is defined by W3C that id **MUST** be unique. And so libraries developers considered it is the case.

Don't use `class` only to group some field this isn't the right usage, the good one to use for this purpose is the attribute `name`. Classes however fits to group by some state of a field.

By the way, if your hidden field is an hidden input on a form, the attribute that use the form tag to send data is the name, not the id. WHich is why you must have different id for radio button but they share the same name.

Comment: If I use Name how to know that it has retrieve the data from the page where the user has clicked

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you add more code to your page, unless you're writing a directive, you shouldn't need using angular.element. You should use `$scope` and `ng-model` to bind your values all together, and to watch for changes in order to trigger some proces you can use `ng-change` or `$scope.$watch()`